# Lenient MUX and Load Signal

Tags: multiplexer, load

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=25&v=d3bF2v056WU

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tggX.png

**I'm going to ask about some names. You could say "they are just names" but if I get some context for the names, its going to going to be a good start to clearing some of my other confusions and understanding the intent of the circuit/ checking if my interpretation of the circuit is actually correct**

1. In what sense is the lenient MUX, "lenient"

My understanding of a MUX: Basically its a truth table. The inputs of S tell you what row of the truth table to go to.

So on what sense does adding a feedback for one output to one row of a truth table (am I wrong about we are feeding back to one row of a truth table) make the MUX "lenient" ?

Also I can't seem to find the term "lenient mux" outside the course's materials

2. What is meant by "load" and "load signal" ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tggX.png

"the select line of the MUX will become the memory component's load signal"

My interpretation of the circuit in the picture is that S will either tell the device to hold onto its current value Q or accept a new one. So my interpretation of S is like its a key that tells locks or unlocks the path to accept a new value.

In what sense are we "loading" and how is S the load signal? We can only store one value Q at a time it seems so it seems we are not loading but setting a value

3. Why is S controlled by a gate? Whose gate?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the 'lenient' part, but for the "load signal", you've misinterpreted the sense of "load".

In this case it doesn't mean "electrical load" or "resistive load" -- rather it is "the signal that 'loads' the value of D into the memory."

---

Taking a shot at 'lenient': this may mean that it does not have oscillation problems between the input and the output when connecting it this way. A bad situation would develop if during a transition there is enough delay and enough gain between the input and output that a self-sustaining oscillation develops. But it is not a term I'm familiar with in this context.

Answer (score -1):

You could checkout [this MIT lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqpg3K6qVqs&index=5&list=PLrRW1w6CGAcXbMtDFj205vALOGmiRc82-) for the answer to the "lenient Multiplexer" part of your question.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. While an MIT link may be safer than most, on Stack Exchange we generally expect answers to contain a body themselves and only refer to links for further reading. Doubtless this is why someone already down-voted. You can edit your answer and flesh out some of the information in the lecture, potentially giving a better voting score in the end.